# Ajax preventdefault doesn't work on codeigniter site

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have a site made with codeigniter and now I want to integrate ajax within one of its views.

I've followed this tutorial [FormgetAjaxCodeigniter](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-jquery-ajax-post/). But since I use  links and want to "get" info from the href instead of using forms, I can't fully use all information from the tutorial. with ajax I rely on preventDefault which isn't working for me at the moment.

The main page is a table of users with bits of important information (ids, names) and has  links with images. I want to use ajax to get a user's id, get all info about that user and display it in a separate table on the same page **through getting the id from the href without activating controller function**

Here is the modified script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".idclenvidi").("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentobj = this;
    var d = {id:$(this).attr('id')};
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : "admin_page/ajax_listclen.php",
        data : d,
        success : function(res){
            if(res){
                  jQuery("div#toptions").show();
                  jQuery("div#toption_id_ajax").html(res.id);
                }
        }
    });
});
```

});

Here is code from the links:

```
<a id="idclenvidi" title="Види сите информации за <?php echo $key['ime'].' '.$key['prezime']; ?>" href="<?php echo base_url()."admin_page/ajax_listclen?id=".$key['id']; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo base_url()."sliki/iconz/if_Search_27877.png" ?>" width="24px" height="24px"></img> </a>
```

Here is code from the controller (ajax)

```
 public function ajax_listclen() {
$data = array(
'id' => $this->input->get('id')
);
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

When I click the link above, the controller submits the function so  preventdefault from ajax doesn't fire.

Since I can't delete the href because I need it for the id, I also can't just put just the id in there because the controller expects a function. The idea was that ajax will just prevent that from happening.

Also to make sure its not some badly included links or scripts on my part here is the include part of my header:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your answers beforehand

Comment: You just forget ```on``` in the statement ```$(".idclenvidi").("click",function(e){```. Change is to this ```$(".idclenvidi").on("click",function(e){```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your selector syntax for the click handler is wrong. You have

```
$(".idclenvidi").("click",function(e){
```

`$(".idclenvidi")` asks for an element with the *class name* "idclenvidi". I believe you want to select by element *id* instead. You also either need to use `.on` or `.click`.

```
$("#idclenvidi").click(function(e){
```

or

```
$("#idclenvidi").on("click",function(e){
```

**Edit to address the comment**

The following address all the issues I think exist in the question code. The example below shows how to do what I believe you're trying to do. I have simplified the example to keep the concepts clear - hopfully.

**Controller**

```
class Admin_page extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['key'] = ['id' => 42]; //bogus data for demo purposes
        $this->load->view('prevent_v', $data);
    }

    public function ajax_listclen()
    {
        $data = $this->input->get('id');
        echo "<p><strong>$data</strong></p>"; //respond with html
    }
}
```

As you can see, the controller returns an html string. This is a tiny bit
easier to deal with in `ajax.success`. If you insist on responding with json the required changes are shown later.

One of the things that looks wrong to me (if I understand what your want to do) is this line

```
var d = {id:$(this).attr('id')};
```

I don't see how this is useful to you. That should give you this javascript object `{id: "idclenvidi"}`. If that's what you want adjust my code accordingly. I think what you really want to send is the value of `$key['id']` so that's what happens below.

The view **prevent_v.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="idclenvidi" title="some title text" 
           href="<?php echo base_url("admin_page/ajax_listclen/{$key['id']}"); ?>"
           >Click Here</a>
        <div id="toptions"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $("#idclenvidi").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //extract the last segment of the URL
                    var val = this.href.substr(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    var d = {id: val};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "prevent/ajax_listclen",
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: d,
                        success: function (res) {
                            $("#toptions").html(res);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Using JSON the `ajax_listclen()` becomes

```
public function ajax_listclen()
{
    $data = ['id' => $this->input->get('id')];
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Then remove `dataType: 'html',` from the ajax options.

Then change the javascript of `success` to

```
success: function (res) {
    var ret = JSON.parse(res);
    $("#toptions").html(ret);
}
```

Hope this helps you sort this out.

Comment: Ok. I changed the header by making it what you said. I also changed the link. I kept the javascriptvoid(0) part, should I remove that? Because it doesn't work. On click the page does nothing. Should the script be like the one above only with what you wrote that needs changing?

Comment: I have edited the answer for a more complete explanation.

Comment: I've tried all of what you wrote, sadly it doesn't work for me. I'm not big on ajax so I don't know where the error really is. I'll accept your answer as true but I will try with using forms and a button since a href isn't working for me. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Dont put any url in the href or you can put javascrtipt:void(0); something like below

```
<a id="idclenvidi" name="idclenvidi" title="Види сите информации за <?php echo $key['ime'].' '.$key['prezime']; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="call_ajax(<?php echo $key['id']; ?>)"> <img src="<?php echo base_url()."sliki/iconz/if_Search_27877.png" ?>" width="24px" height="24px"></img> </a>

    <script>
     call_ajax(d){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : "admin_page/ajax_listclen",
        data : {id:d},
        success : function(res){
            if(res){
                  jQuery("div#toptions").show();
                  jQuery("div#toption_id_ajax").html(res.id);
                }
        }
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I've tried what you said but how to send id now? I tried call_ajax(<?php echo $key['id]; ?> but when I click it nothing happens.

Comment: The link looks like this now " <a id="idclenvidi" name="idclenvidi" title="Види сите информации за <?php echo $key['ime'].' '.$key['prezime']; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="call_ajax(<?php echo $key['id']; ?>)"> <img src="<?php echo base_url()."sliki/iconz/if_Search_27877.png" ?>" width="24px" height="24px"></img> </a>"

Comment: You will need to catch the id in the javascript function too, like below

<script>
call_ajax(id){}

</script>

Comment: I changed the main function now its call_ajax(d) { } instead of the two lines and everything else is the same. Check above ajax code  EDIT: I tried your latest advice, didn't work.

Comment: @DavidDr. check the answer above, I have updated the code

Comment: Ok updated it, changed everything. Still doesn't work, only now it shows the controller function in the address bar. Doesn't submit which is good

Comment: Check if you can access the url from postman or directly from browser. I dont think if you are using codeigneiter then you have to define the url like  url : "admin_page/ajax_listclen.php", I guess  you dont have to give .php in your url. Anyway make sure your url is working first. PS I have updated the code I am not sure if it will work, its your job to make sure backend is working

Comment: Thank you for your help. I haven't sorted the problem but I will assume its something on my part.